# How to show alerts on bad request, but redirect on success?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a registration form, the user is being redirected to home.php after success (works)

But also all the 'alerts/errors' which are echos in PHP, after submit, will redirect to register.php and show the error in blank white page.

(How do i display them to `<div class="msg">` position?)

```html
<script>
        document.querySelector(".register form").addEventListener("submit", async (e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
            const form = e.target
            const body = new FormData(form)
            // fetch is much easier to use than XHR
            const res = await fetch(form.action, {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {accept: "application/json", // let PHP know what type of response we want},
                body})
            const data = await res.json()
            if (res.ok) {
                location.href = data.location
            } else if (res.status === 400) {
                document.querySelector('.msg').textContent = data.message
                // also do something with data.errors maybe
            }
        })
    </script>

    <body>
    <div class="msg"></div>  <!--position for error/ wrong pass etc-->
```

---

[**register.php**](https://pastebin.com/raw/bVPXDPsq)

Based off that, please provide a correct code snippet in order to mark this as resolved.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/bVPXDPsq <-- register.php

Comment: In a suggested edit to your post, user @contributor01010 also shows another issue with your JavaScript: your comment next to the `"application/json"` header also comments out the curly bracket on that line. While this isn't a correct use case for editing, it might be another factor contributing to your problem: I'd recommend you learn how to use your browser's developer tools so you can find these sorts of problems yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would probably make your life quite a bit easier if you always returned JSON from your PHP, rather than sometimes HTML as well.

For examples, when checking the errors at the top of `register.php`, you should return JSON objects --- e.g.

```
{error: "Email is not valid!"}
```

rather than their HTML equivilents.

---

This means that in your `fetch`, you'll now always be able to get the JSON content (currently, you'd probably get an error in your browser's debug console if one of those messages came back, as it's not valid JSON). Then, in your JavaScript, you can just detect this and switch however you want:

```
if (data.error) { // If there is an error
    document.querySelector(".msg").textContent = data.error;
}
else if (data.location) { // If we want to redirect the user somewhere
    window.location.href = "./" + data.location;
}
```

Comment: How can i always return json from my PHP (for the errors) i tried ```exit(json_encode(["Passwords do not match"]));``` but doesn't work

Comment: JSON objects (by definition) are sets of _keys_ and _values_. While PHP will allow you to use `json_encode` on an array, it won't have a `.error` key when JS tries to read it. `exit(json_encode(["error"=>"Passwords do not match"]))` should work, but you can also consider just writing the JSON by hand for this one, as it never changes: `exit('{"error": "Passwords do not match"}')`.

Comment: I get "data is not defined" for the javascript (data.error)

Comment: I've cleaned up / simplified your code a little, let me know if these versions work: [JS](https://pastebin.com/jXL6b5ab), [PHP](https://pastebin.com/jvjr90Fh)

Comment: It works, i will read it 100 times and understand what you gone through, i been trying to resolve this for a week now, you're a legend

Comment: OH -- i see that even the redirect response should be in json format, ```exit('{"location": "home.php"}');```  Well, that makes perfect sense

Comment: Also to finish this, what is the correct way to output JSON into HTML (To Add CSS)? (Like i did with the divs+ style before to show the alerts in a box etc)

Comment: Yeah for sure, you can make divs, etc with JS. A simple way could be `document.querySelector(".msg").innerHTML = \`<div class="error form">${data.error}</div>\`;`, but there are definitely better patterns out there --- I'd suggest looking into the DOM methods pages on MDN as a good starting point, etc.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but how can i keep .innerHTML + .textContent? sorry i started learning

Comment: If you're looking to keep the existing text contents and then just also add in the error message text, I'd suggest actually just adding in an empty `span` or `div` in your HTML code which will contain the error message, and then using `.innerHTML` on that --- that way, you only change the contents of that element, while preserving the text above it. The other benefit is then you can add the classes in the HTML, rather than in JS.

Comment: I tried but it will still be plain text ```<div class="msg" class="error form"></div>``` ```document.querySelector(".msg").innerHTML = data.error;```

Comment: Any chance you could post a (small) part of your HTML & CSS to pastebin so I can take a look? One other small thing to note is that for each attribute in HTML (for example, `class`), it's best practice to only declare it once --- what I mean by this is you should write `<div class="msg error form"></div>` rather than having two `class` attributes there. Also, probably better to use a unqiue `id` for this query (e.g. `id="msg"` and then `#msg` in `querySelector`), as otherwise `querySelector` only finds the _first_ element with the class, not necessarily the one you want to change.

Comment: sure, https://codepen.io/bob69420x/pen/KKvoMVQ

Comment: I've tried running this, it seems to work file for me to get this output: https://i.imgur.com/KnXDjEu.png if I remove the `top` and `left` rules in the CSS (which move the element past the top-left corner of the screen). Are you trying to do some sort of animation on this (e.g. move this down from the top of the screen when there is an error)? If not, consider just setting those values to some non-negative numbers.